# How to install JSTL? The absolute uri: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core cannot be resolved

Tags: jsp, tomcat, jstl

This is my JSP page's taglib directive:

`<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>`

I'm getting the following ERROR :

```
HTTP Status 500 - 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
type Exception report
message 
description The server encountered an internal error () that prevented it from fulfilling this request.
exception 
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: The absolute uri: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core cannot be resolved in either web.xml or the jar files deployed with this application
org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.jspError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:51)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.dispatch(ErrorDispatcher.java:409)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.jspError(ErrorDispatcher.java:116)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.TagLibraryInfoImpl.generateTLDLocation(TagLibraryInfoImpl.java:315)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.TagLibraryInfoImpl.<init>(TagLibraryInfoImpl.java:148)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseTaglibDirective(Parser.java:420)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseDirective(Parser.java:476)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseElements(Parser.java:1426)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parse(Parser.java:133)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.ParserController.doParse(ParserController.java:215)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.ParserController.parse(ParserController.java:102)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.generateJava(Compiler.java:167)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:306)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:286)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:273)
org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:566)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:308)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:320)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:266)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)
```

I have added the JAR file *jstl.jar* and *standard.jar* in the */WEB-INF/lib* folder.
Can anyone tell me where I'm making the mistake?

Comment: What server are you running on? Newer containers include JSTL already, and packing your own copies might confuse matters.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It look like that you're using JSTL 1.0 with taglib URIs of 1.1/1.2. You have JSTL in different versions:

- **1.0**: exist of two JAR files `jstl.jar` and `standard.jar`. Taglib URI is has no `/jsp` in path and library name is suffixed with `_rt` like `http://java.sun.com/jstl/core_rt`. Came along and requires at minimum Servlet 2.3 / JSP 1.2. Is end of life, do not use it nowadays.
- **1.1**: exist of same JAR files as 1.0. Taglib URI has no suffix and includes `/jsp` in the path like `http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core`. Came along and requires at minimum Servlet 2.4 / JSP 2.0.
- **1.2**: exist of one JAR file `jstl-1.2.jar` and has same tagtlib URI as 1.1. Came along with Servlet 2.5 / JSP 2.0 but works at Servlet 2.4 / JSP 2.0 as well.

You can find the exact JSTL version by extracting the JAR file with a zip tool and reading the `MANIFEST.MF` file.

The Servlet/JSP version depends on the webcontainer/application server used (even more, it **is** a Servlet/JSP implementation) and version level is configureable in `web.xml`. If you're using at least Servlet 2.5 / JSP 2.0 implementation such as Tomcat 6.0, then I'd recommend to just pick JSTL 1.2. Installing JSTL shouldn't be that hard:

1. Place the [jstl-1.2.jar](https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/javax/servlet/jstl/1.2/jstl-1.2.jar) file in `Webapp/WEB-INF/lib`. Or when you're using Maven:

   ```
   <dependency>
       <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
       <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
       <version>1.2</version>
   </dependency>
   ```
2. Declare the taglib in JSP file with the right TLD URI. You can find [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/) the TLD documentation which applies on both JSTL 1.1 and JSTL 1.2. Click the taglib of interest to get the declaration examples.

Ensure that you have no duplicates of older JSTL versions in the classpath (includes `JRE/lib` and `Appserver/lib`) to avoid collisions. If you have full admin-level control over the appserver, then you could also place the JAR file(s) in `Appserver/lib` instead of `Webapp/WEB-INF/lib` so that it get applied on all deployed webapps. At least do NOT extract the JAR file(s) and clutter the classpath with its contents (the loose TLD files) and/or declare the taglibs in *your* webapp's `web.xml` as some poor online tutorials suggests.

The servlet version declaration in `web.xml` has also incfluence on functioning of JSTL. Common practice is that you declare it to the highest which your webcontainer/appserver supports. In case of Servlet 3.0, the `web.xml` should look like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app 
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    version="3.0">
    
    <!-- Config here. -->

</web-app>
```

Make sure that you don't have a `<!DOCTYPE ...>` in there, otherwise it will run in Servlet 2.3 compatibility modus and then EL expressions will stop working.

#### See also:

- [Our JSTL wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info)
- [How to install JSTL? The absolute uri: http://java.sun.com/jstl/core cannot be resolved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4928271/how-to-install-jstl-the-absolute-uri-http-java-sun-com-jstl-core-cannot-be-r)
- [EL expressions not evaluated in JSP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30080810/el-expressions-not-evaluated-anymore-after-including-jstl-in-webapp)

Comment: Awesomely helpful and informative answer! If no other, you have at least my upvote for greatly amplifying on the bit of info I had.

Answer (score 2):

When declaring a `tabglib` like you did, the URI is used to uniquely identify each taglib in an internal registry of taglibs, much like a key is used to set/get values from a `HashMap` or `Hashtable` in Java.

As per Sun specifications, resolving the URIs to actual tag libraries that can be loaded/called by the application takes place in the following order:

1. Check the `web.xml` file for matching `taglib` tags that have the given URI in them and then follow the `taglib-location` tag to actually load the TLD.
2. If no match with #1 was found, recursively check the `META-INF` directory of all the JARs in the application for TLDs that contain the URI that was specified.

In you case, *the absolute uri: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core cannot be resolved in either web.xml or the jar files deployed with this application* as indicated by the `org.apache.jasper.JasperException` so there must be a mismatch somewhere (between the URI and the corresponding JSTL version).

Here, my guess is that you have deployed `jstl.jar` and `standard.jar` from JSTL 1.0. To verifiy this, open the file `META-INF/c.tld` of `standard.jar` and find the `uri` element. If what you can read is `<uri>http://java.sun.com/jstl/core</uri>`, then you've found the issue.

So, to solve the problem, either change your taglib declaration in your JSPs like this:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
```

Or (and this this IMHO the preferred solution), upgrade your JSTL version to match the version expected by the JSPs, i.e. use JSTL 1.1. You can download this version from [here](http://jakarta.apache.org/taglibs/doc/standard-doc/intro.html). Then, just put the `jstl.jar` and `standard.jar` in your `WEB-INF/lib` (if you check `META-INF/c.tld` in `standard.jar`, you'll see that it declares the `<uri>http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core</uri>`).

Answer (score 1):

For reasons which probably seemed like a good idea, the "inventors" of JSTL changed the URL between versions 2.2 and 2.3 (I think). I've cursed about this on several occasions.

For a first approximation, you could try removing the "jsp" from the URI cited.

There's more, interesting but confusing, information on this problem here: http://forums.sun.com/thread.jspa?threadID=486791

Answer (score 0):

the only solution that helped me in a similar situation was to declare the following dependencies in the pom

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
   <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
   <version>2.5</version>
   <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
   <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
   <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
   <version>2.1</version>
   <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
   <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
   <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
   <version>1.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
   <artifactId>el-api</artifactId>
   <version>6.0.26</version>
   <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
   <artifactId>jasper-el</artifactId>
   <version>6.0.26</version>
   <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

as described [here](http://blog.flurdy.com/2010/07/jetty-tomcat-jsp.html)

Answer (score -3):

If possible, use the local path of tld instead of `http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core`, like this:

```
<%@ taglib uri="./tld/core.tld" prefix="c" %>
```

Comment: This is a `URI`, not a `URL`, relative paths don't make sense in this case, and although some containers might allow that, it's non-standard and non-portable.