# JSTL how to output data from request

Tags: java, jsp, jstl

I've got a servlet that puts something in request but I can't call it with jstl. What am i doing wrong?

```
<%@ page import="beans.Patient"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ taglib uri='http://java.sun.com/jstl/fmt' prefix='fmt' %>
<jsp:useBean id="patBean" class="beans.Patient" scope="session"/>
<c:set var="patientName" value="${patient.name}"/>

<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
</head>
<body>
test
<form action="PatientAction" method="post">
<input type="text" name="patientId" id="patientId"></input>
<input type="submit"/>
</form>

<c:out value="${patientName}" />
<c:out value="${patBean.name}" />
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to bother with `<useBean>` when you're using JSTL, just refer to the bean directly. So if your servlet put a `Patient` into the session, you can get its name using:

```
<c:out value="${patient.name}" />
```

Comment: it just comes out as text in the webpage like this: "${patient.name}"

Comment: @user521180: That means JSP EL isn't enabled for your webapp.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2168832/expression-language-in-jsp-not-working/2168974#2168974

Comment: Thank. that worked. it turns out i wasnt using 2.4 on my web.xml

Comment: You've got another problem: your JSTL core is declared as per JSTL 1.1/1.2, but your JSTL fmt doesn't comply it. Align it as well to comply JSTL 1.1. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1896449/tag-library-descriptor/1896610#1896610

Answer (score 1):

request attributes are accessible via the name they have been put in . If you have had `request.setAttribute("foo", fooValue)` then it is accessible via `${foo}`. This is true if you are within the same request. This means the servlet has to do a *forward* rather than a *redirect*. If a redirect happens, that's a new request, and the old values are lost.

Comment: it just comes out as text "${patient.name}"