# JSTL and Format errors

Tags: jsp, jstl

Following the code.

```
<c:set var="birthdate"  value="${requestScope.evaluation.employee.birthDate}"></c:set>
<fmt:formatDate pattern="ddMMyyyy"  type="both" value="${birthdate}"/>
```

Error:
Custom tag attribute value cannot be runtime expression. value: "[${birthdate}]"

Comment: Can we see your taglib declarations at the top of the JSP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ensure that the JSTL `fmt` taglib is declared as per [JSTL 1.1 documentation](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/fmt/tld-summary.html):

```
<%@ taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" %>
```

Note the `/jsp` path.

#### See also:

- [How to install/use JSTL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1896449/tag-library-descriptor/1896610#1896610)