# Convert and format a Date in JSP

Tags: jsp, date-format

From my JSP Page, I am getting `Date` in this format.

> Fri May 13 2011 19:59:09 GMT 0530 (India Standard Time)

How can I convert this to the pattern `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss`?

Comment: Have you tried taking a look at the javadocs? Google 'java date format' and see what comes up.

Comment: Don't you actually mean "In my JSP page" instead of "From my JSP page"?

Comment: Any chance you want to switch your answer to the overwhelming community favorite?

Comment: Never have I seen so many negatively voted answers to a single question. At least it's obvious which is the correct answer.

Answer (score -12, accepted):

You can do that using the `SimpleDateFormat` class.

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");

String dates=formatter.format(mydate);
//mydate is your date object
```

Comment: I assume that the downvoting is for a) using scriptlets and b) for not even doing the carets around it / returning the formatted date and c) it is the accepted answer altough the fmt:formatDate answer is the better choice. At least thats why I am tempted to downvote it.

Comment: In JSP is better to use tags instead.
`<%@ taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" %>`
 `<fmt:formatDate value="${bean.date}" pattern="yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss" />`

Comment: Most voted answer is for convert Java Date object to display in the JSP. But the question asked when a Date object is returned to the back-end (probably a Java class) from a JSP how to convert it of format it to a more readable pattern. So I think this answer does give an answer to the question (It's  obvious because this is the accepted one).

Comment: @Prime: the format `Fri May 13 2011 19:59:09 GMT 0530 (India Standard Time)` is typical to `Date#toString()`, which means that he already has a `java.util.Date` object at hands which could impossibly come from a JSP file as HTTP request parameters are always `java.lang.String` (even then, converting `String` to `Date` would require knowlegde of `SimpleDateFormat`, which the OP apparently didn't have, otherwise he didn't ask this question at all).

Answer (score 273):

In JSP, you'd normally like to use [JSTL](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info) [`<fmt:formatDate>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/fmt/formatDate.html) for this. You can of course also throw in a *scriptlet* with `SimpleDateFormat`, but *scriptlets* are [strongly discouraged](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/how-to-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files) since 2003.

Assuming that `${bean.date}` returns `java.util.Date`, here's how you can use it:

```xml
<%@ taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" %>
...
<fmt:formatDate value="${bean.date}" pattern="yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss" />
```

If you're actually using a `java.util.Calendar`, then you can invoke its `getTime()` method to get a `java.util.Date` out of it that `<fmt:formatDate>` accepts:

```xml
<fmt:formatDate value="${bean.calendar.time}" pattern="yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss" />
```

Or, if you're actually holding the date in a `java.lang.String` (this indicates a serious design mistake in the model; you should really fix your model to store dates as `java.util.Date` instead of as `java.lang.String`!), here's how you can convert from one date string format e.g. `MM/dd/yyyy` to another date string format e.g. `yyyy-MM-dd` with help of JSTL [`<fmt:parseDate>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/fmt/parseDate.html).

```xml
<fmt:parseDate pattern="MM/dd/yyyy" value="${bean.dateString}" var="parsedDate" />
<fmt:formatDate value="${parsedDate}" pattern="yyyy-MM-dd" />
```

Comment: i like you to add how to store the ${bean.date} to return java.util.date

Comment: @shareef: Just go through a basic JSP/Servlet tutorial. Our servlets wiki page is a good starting point to find references http://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info

Comment: I thought this example was well written.  Unfortunately it did not work for me even though in my case bean.date does return a java.util.Date!   >> According to TLD or attribute directive in tag file, attribute [value] does not accept any expressions

Comment: @user1445967: Your JSTL installation is corrupted. Follow https://stackoverflow.com/a/4928309 for instructions. Most likely you have a `standard.jar` of JSTL 1.0 lingering around in runtime classpath. Get rid of it.

Answer (score 11):

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
 pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html dir="ltr" lang="en-US">
 <head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <title>JSP with the current date</title>
  </head>
 <body>
 <%java.text.DateFormat df = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy"); %>
<h1>Current Date: <%= df.format(new java.util.Date()) %> </h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Output: Current Date: 10/03/2010

Comment: The op want yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss and not dd/MM/yyyy

Answer (score 0):

```
Date td = new Date();
String b = new String("");
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("YYYY/MM/dd");
b = format.format(td);
out.println(b);
```

Answer (score -3):

The example above showing the import with ...sun.com/jsp/jstl/format is incorrect (meaning it didn't work for me).

Instead try the below -this import statement is valid

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core" prefix="c" %><%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core-rt" prefix="c-rt" %><%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jstl/fmt" prefix="fmt" %>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Format Date</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <c-rt:set var="now" value="<%=new java.util.Date()%>" />

    <table border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"
    style="border-collapse: collapse" bordercolor="#111111"
    width="63%" id="AutoNumber2">
      <tr>
        <td width="100%" colspan="2" bgcolor="#0000FF">
          <p align="center">
            <b>
              <font color="#FFFFFF" size="4">Formatting: 
              <fmt:formatDate value="${now}" type="both"
              timeStyle="long" dateStyle="long" />
              </font>
            </b>
          </p>
        </td>
      </tr>
```

Comment: My answer is correct. Your problem is just caused by that you're using the 10 year old and deprecated JSTL prototype library instead of the more recent ones. The newer taglib URI with `/jsp` in the path was introduced with JSTL 1.1 around november 2003. We're in 2011 already. Figure how out of date you are... Keep yourself and your libraries up to date.

Answer (score -3):

```
<%@page import="java.text.SimpleDateFormat"%>
<%@page import="java.util.Date"%>
<%@page import="java.util.Locale"%>

<html>
<head>
<title>Date Format</title>
</head>
<body>
<%
String stringDate = "Fri May 13 2011 19:59:09 GMT 0530";
Date stringDate1 = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss Z", Locale.ENGLISH).parse(stringDate);
String stringDate2 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").format(stringDate1);

out.println(stringDate2);
%>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please put your answer always in context instead of just pasting code. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) for more details.