# Convert date format Thu Aug 14 00:00:00 AST 2014

Tags: jsp

"docdate" is a column in database under type Date
appear in JSP in this (Thu Aug 14 00:00:00 AST 2014) I used this statement

```
<td><%=child.get("docdate")%></td>
```

I need it to appear in dd/MM/yyyy format.
I tried this statement

```
<td><%=sdf.format((Date)child.getdocdate())%></td>
```

But it doesn't work.

Comment: why the javascript tag??

Comment: possible duplicate of [Where can I find documentation on formatting a date in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056728/where-can-i-find-documentation-on-formatting-a-date-in-javascript)

Comment: Use momentjs  it's a library available for using in browser and node projects
should use this pattern: moment().format("D-MM-YYYY",'h:mm:ss a' AST 2014);

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6162401/formatting-a-date-in-jsp

Comment: implement many answer but not work thanks to all

Comment: I read many of the common themes with my question, but all of them did not work
I have a feeling that the code is very simple, but I do not know