# How to convert date format from yyyy/dd/mm into mm/dd/yyyy in mysql using jsp code?

Tags: mysql, jsp

I have used date picker in the front end which is in the format of mm/dd/yyyy and i have selected date data type in mysql then how to write code for it to convert from yyyy/dd/mm to mm/dd/yyy using jsp. I have tried code but not working please help me

```html
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Reg</title>
</head>
<body>
<%@ page import ="java.sql.*" %>
<%@ page import ="javax.sql.*" %>
<%

String leave_category=request.getParameter("leave"); 
String reason=request.getParameter("reas"); 
String days=request.getParameter("difference"); 
String start_date=request.getParameter("color"); 
String end_date=request.getParameter("color"); 

Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"); 
java.sql.Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test","root",""); 
Statement st= con.createStatement(); 
ResultSet rs; 
int i=st.executeUpdate("insert into leave_for values ( '"+leave_category+"','"+reason+"','"+days+"','"+start_date+"','"+end_date+"')"); 
out.println("Registered"); 
response.sendRedirect("LeaveForm1.jsp");


%>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert and format a Date in JSP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6162401/convert-and-format-a-date-in-jsp)

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/a/6162507/1760116

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
select str_to_date("03/02/2009","%d/%m/%Y");
```

It will give:

```
2009-02-03
```