# How to display only date on jsp?

Tags: javascript, jsp

my jsp gonna load data from table and one of my table's column is date which saved in datetime `2017-09-26 00:00:00.0`

how do I display only date `2017-09-26` on jsp?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6162401/convert-and-format-a-date-in-jsp

Comment: thank you!!! i can't find any spesific cases before

Answer (score 0):

using the formatDate library `<%@ taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" %>`

and give it a pattern

```
<fmt:formatDate value="${bean.date}" pattern="yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss" />
```

source: [Convert and format a Date in JSP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6162401/convert-and-format-a-date-in-jsp)