# Add slash in DATE YYYMMDD and Colon in TIME HHmm in jstl

Tags: jstl

I'm getting two variables From `DB` Date and time (`${COLL.date}`,`${COLL.time}`).

The two variables values are like this `20160719` and `1234`

I want to format this two variables like this `2016/07/19` and `12:34`

In my `JSP` page, I haded this library

```
<%@ taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt"%>
```

And I set tag

```
<fmt:parseDate pattern="yyyy/MM/dd" value="${COLL.date}" var="parsedDate" />
<fmt:formatDate value="${parsedDate}" pattern="yyyy/MM/dd" var="dateformat"/>

<p>${dateformat}</p>
```

This is my variable `${COLL.date}` (`20160719`), Which I'm getting from my DB.

When I do like above, I'm getting an ERROR

Comment: @JasperdeVries Already I tried with your suggested Question but is not Working

Comment: Tried what? Nothing about that in your question. Please [edit] it and update it with what you tried. Just curious: where does `${COLL.date}` come from? It looks like it is already formatted from a date object.

Comment: @JasperdeVries ${COLL.date} this is the variable, I'm getting from DB. I already posted, What I tried

Comment: So, in your database, you are not storing it as a date type? It would be better to have a date type. Then, your `parseDate pattern` should be `yyyyMMdd` without the slashes.

Comment: @JasperdeVries I'm using MongoDB and I'm not doing for insertion part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, so you've followed the instructions from the answer on [Convert and format a Date in JSP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6162401/convert-and-format-a-date-in-jsp). Your `parseDate` format is wrong though. And, you could throw in the time as well in one go, so:

```
<fmt:parseDate pattern="yyyyMMdd HHmm" value="${COLL.date} ${COLL.time}" var="parsedDate" />
<fmt:formatDate value="${parsedDate}" pattern="yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm" />
```

If you need to output the date and time separately, use:

```
<fmt:parseDate pattern="yyyyMMdd HHmm" value="${COLL.date} ${COLL.time}" var="parsedDate" />
<fmt:formatDate value="${parsedDate}" pattern="yyyy/MM/dd" />
<fmt:formatDate value="${parsedDate}" pattern="HH:mm" />
```

Comment: I tried With Date, not time, I got output like this  Tue Jul 19 00:00:00 IST 2016. But I'm looking for this format 2016/07/19 and also I want to date & time separate variable

Comment: Using a variable is optional but certainly not required. You could use them if you like, but it will not effect formatting in any way.