# How to display a localdatetime in separate date and time on jsp page?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, jsp

I have a spring mvc project and Im displaying event start and end times on a jsp page. The events are stored in my database as localdatetime and I am retrieving them from my database and then displaying them.
I am displaying them on my jsp page like this

```
<c:forEach items="${eventList}" var="events">
<tr>
<td>${events.getId()}</td>
<td>${events.getStart()} - ${events.getEnd()}</td>
</tr>
</c:forEach>
```

They are displaying like this 
2019-04-28T11:30 - 2019-04-28T14:30

Is it possible to display the date and time separately?

EDITED:
This is the code for my backend, where i am getting them events from my database

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/events", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String getEvents(Model model) {

        List<Event> events = eventService.findAll();
        model.addAttribute("eventList", events);
        return "events";
    }
```

The problem is how can i display them as the start/end as a separate date and time when they being added to the model as a localdatetime?

Comment: split: Splits a string into an array.Try .split('T'), refer this https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnalg.html

Comment: Can you post your complete jsp page ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6162401/convert-and-format-a-date-in-jsp
Check this. Hope this will help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use new Date & Time Api [Java 8].

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html#toLocalDate--

```
LocalDateTime dt = LocalDateTime.now();
System.out.println("Local Date : " + dt.toLocalDate());
System.out.println("Local Date : " + dt.toLocalTime());
```

Answer (score 0):

The method `split()` breaks a string into many substrings using a character. It returns a array with the strings. Example:

```
String date = 2019-04-28T11:30
String array[] = new String[2]
array = date.split("T");
```

Now the array is 
`["2019-04-28","11:30"]`.
And if you want to split the date

```
date = array[1]
String array2[] = new String[3]
array2 = date.split("-");
```

Now the array2 is 
`["2019","04","28"]`.

Comment: Ive edited my question a bit, as I don't think split will work for me. Can i use split on my jsp page side?