# Running WebApplication through Tomcat server

Tags: jsp, tomcat

I deployed my webapplicaton sucessffully,index page is running well but when i tried to navigate to login page an error message comes like these....

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: The absolute uri: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core cannot be resolved in either web.xml or the jar files deployed with this application
org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.jspError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:56)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.dispatch(ErrorDispatcher.java:410)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.jspError(ErrorDispatcher.java:117)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.TagLibraryInfoImpl.generateTLDLocation(TagLibraryInfoImpl.java:311)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.TagLibraryInfoImpl.<init>(TagLibraryInfoImpl.java:152)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseTaglibDirective(Parser.java:410)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseDirective(Parser.java:475)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseElements(Parser.java:1427)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parse(Parser.java:138)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.ParserController.doParse(ParserController.java:242)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.ParserController.parse(ParserController.java:102)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.generateJava(Compiler.java:198)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:373)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:353)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:340)
org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:646)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:357)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
```

Comment: seems to be no body who can help me out of this situation!!! please help.....

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4928271/jstl-1-2-the-absolute-uri-http-java-sun-com-jstl-core-cannot-be-resolved

Comment: what version of JSTL do you have in your classpath?

Comment: thank you for the reply,the version is not mentioned in the jar file.
I have tomcat 7.0.26 ,so what version of jstl.jar should i have?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have these 2 jar files in your web application:

- jstl.jar
- standard.jar.

For Tomcat 7.x.x you need **jstl1.2** jar.