# Adding external rar files to Cloud Foundry

Tags: java, cloud-foundry

Hi I just got started with CloudFoundry and deployed a project. My project uses some rar files so how do I attach rar files to the deployed page that uses those rar files.

More Details:
My page is a jsp page and uses jstl. Because of the jstl rar files the container in this case Class Foundry cant find them. My jsp page has the directive <%@ taglib uri="java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"; prefix="c" %> . If i add the rar files to the Webcontent folder of my eclipse project i still get the error "org.apache.jasper.JasperException: The absolute uri: java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core cannot be resolved in either web.xml or the jar files deployed with this applicationorg.apache..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember that Cloud Foundry is using Tomcat 6 as it's Container. So a best test case for your situation is to test out your app with local tomcat 6.

Also I assume you have this in place already:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    <version>1.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Or if you manually include the JSTL jar:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    <version>1.2</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

This link also has more useful details for you as well:

http://www.coderanch.com/how-to/java/JstlTagLibDefinitions

Let us know how it goes.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to make the RAR files part of package that will be deployed. That means you can either put them in resource folder and reference them where needed. If you can let us know more details on what are you trying to achieve, we could help more.

Can you deploy your application to a standalone container like tomcat and see results? Also the issue in your case seems more of application issue than the CloudFoundry issue. Check similar issues at:
http://forums.netbeans.org/topic28571.html 
and
[How to install JSTL? The absolute uri: http://java.sun.com/jstl/core cannot be resolved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4928271/jstl-1-2-the-absolute-uri-http-java-sun-com-jstl-core-cannot-be-resolved)

If you arrive at conclusion that your app is fine, raise a CloudFoundry ticket, but I feel the issue is with your application

Comment: Well my page is a jsp page and uses jstl. Because of the jstl rar files the container in this case Class Foundry cant find them. My jsp page has the directive   <%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>  . If i add the rar files to the Webcontent folder of my eclipse project i still get the error "org.apache.jasper.JasperException: The absolute uri: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core cannot be resolved in either web.xml or the jar files deployed with this applicationorg.apache...

Comment: I think this comment needs to be moved to the question to make it a clear and complete question.

Comment: Has anyone found a solution to this problem ??