# JSTL if tag always execute as true

Tags: java, jsp, if-statement, jstl, jsp-tags

I am working with a JSTL and trying to implement a `if` tag

below is my code for file `login.tag`

```jsp
<c:if test="${not empty param.error}">
        //do something
</c:if>
```

My understanding is when I access this page

```
with path/index.jsp   //the if tag is not executed 
with path/index.jsp?error=wrongpassword   //the if tag is executed
```

But what I am getting now is the `if` tag is always execute `true`, Please advice

Comment: Check the generated HTML code. My guess is that it contains <c:if ...>, which means that the if tag is not interpreted, probably because you didn't declare the code library at the top of the JSP.

Comment: I have checked the html , the c:if is printed in html , what does that mean?

Comment: It means that the if tag is not interpreted, probably because you didn't declare the code library at the top of the JSP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use `c:if` tag you should use JSP taglib directive for JSTL core tag library. Use below code at the top of the JSP

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
```

You also need libraries for JSTL as dependencies to your project. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15435124/573032) answer to find maven dependencies.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning adding dependencies , Finally get it to work as expected!