# How to make JSTL library work in Tomcat 7 on Ubuntu

Tags: jsp, tomcat, jstl

I am using Tomcat 7.0.61 on **Ubuntu 14.02 LTS** and I can see the `lib` directory existing in the **`/usr/share/tomcat7`** folder.

The typical webapps folder for Tomcat is

**`/var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/ROOT/`**

Then I created the separated folder for my web application called `myjsp` and everything seemed to work really fine because until I tried to install the **JSTL taglib library** downloaded from the tomcat portal.

On Windows, I put the JSTL jar file in the **`C:/tomcat7/lib`** directory which may serve as the shared folder for all applications as far as I know. And it works on Windows because I could import the library in the scripts.

But on Ubuntu right now, nothing is likely to properly work on my system. I have tried moving the JAR file to the **`/usr/share/tomcat7/lib`** and in **`/var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/myjsp/WEB-INF/lib`**

So where should I put the JSTL JAR file in?

Note: I created the **`WEB-INF` folder** manually with the only folder in there which is **`lib`** folder

Comment: Read http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info: for servlet 3.0, there are 2 jar files to download. And they should be in the WEB-INF/lib folder of your webapp.

Comment: I have to create WEB-INF/lib manually, is that right? So the directory tree is something like this /var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/ROOT/myapp/WEB-INF/lib

Comment: myapp must not be inside ROOT. ROOT is itself a webapp.

Comment: Thank you very much, that gives me an idea

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't put anything to the `ROOT`, because if you undeploy your app the root context will be shown to the user. Use the following path

```
/var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/myapp
```

Make sure you have used an environment variable and system property for

```
CATALINA_BASE=/var/lib/tomcat7
```

To deploy the application better to create `.war` file and put it into `webapps` either manually or better using a tomcat manager app. The tomcat is configured by default to start automatic deployment if you put a file to the `webapps`.
All libraries in the `war` should be in `/WEB-INF/lib`.

You can use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15435124/573032) answer to download required jars from accredited sources.