# The method setDisabled(boolean) in the type BaseHandlerTag is not applicable for the arguments (String)

Tags: jsp, struts

In Below code from a .jspf file, set a var disabled for boolean value and using that var later in code but in weblogic deployment throughing below error. Disabled property is not working.

```
Error
 editAgreement.jsp:85:18: Error in "editServiceAttribute.jspf" at line 159: The method setDisabled(boolean) in the type BaseHandlerTag is not applicable for the arguments (String)
            file="/WEB-INF/xct/jsp/serviceattribute/editServiceAttribute.jspf"%>
```

**JSP code**

```
<html:html><c:set var="disabled" value="${Boolean.false}"/>

<html-el:multibox name="${formName}" property="calculated_selectedAttributeList" disabled="${Boolean.valueOf(disabled)}" errorStyleClass="error">

<html-el:multibox name="${formName}" property="calculated_selectedAttributeList" disabled="${disabled}" errorStyleClass="error">
```

**TLD declaration**

```
<%@ taglib uri="/WEB-INF/struts-tiles.tld" prefix="tiles" %>

<%@ taglib uri="/WEB-INF/struts-logic.tld" prefix="logic" %>
<%@ taglib uri="/WEB-INF/struts-logic-el.tld" prefix="logic-el" %>

<%@ taglib uri="/WEB-INF/struts-html.tld" prefix="html" %>
<%@ taglib uri="/WEB-INF/struts-html-el.tld" prefix="html-el" %>

<%@ taglib uri="/WEB-INF/struts-bean.tld" prefix="bean" %>
<%@ taglib uri="/WEB-INF/struts-bean-el.tld" prefix="bean-el" %>

<%@ taglib uri="/WEB-INF/taglibs-datetime.tld" prefix="dt" %>
```

Comment: pls post the tag library used, and a part of jspf where value is being set

Comment: tag library please..???/

Comment: try using `Boolean.parseBoolean(disabled)`

Comment: I am using below taglibs

Comment: <%@ taglib uri="/WEB-INF/struts-tiles.tld" prefix="tiles" %>                        
<%@ taglib uri="/WEB-INF/struts-logic.tld" prefix="logic" %>                      
<%@ taglib uri="/WEB-INF/struts-logic-el.tld" prefix="logic-el" %>              
<%@ taglib uri="/WEB-INF/struts-html.tld" prefix="html" %>                       
<%@ taglib uri="/WEB-INF/struts-html-el.tld" prefix="html-el" %>               
<%@ taglib uri="/WEB-INF/struts-bean.tld" prefix="bean" %>
<%@ taglib uri="/WEB-INF/struts-bean-el.tld" prefix="bean-el" %>
<%@ taglib uri="/WEB-INF/taglibs-datetime.tld" prefix="dt" %>

Comment: have u tried this `Boolean.parseBoolean(disabled)`

Comment: I have tried Boolean.parseBoolean(disabled) also but not working.

Comment: You originally called and tagged this all JSTL. This is **not** JSTL. To learn what JSTL really is head to http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info

Comment: I am using <%@ taglib uri="/WEB-INF/c.tld" prefix="c" %> for JSTL

Comment: This is unclear but it seems you can't use a taglibrary in such way. You need to use URL like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15435124/573032).