# Exception when use Jsp Taglib

Tags: jstl, taglib

When i use JSP TagLib I get this exception:

```
Servlet.service() for servlet ProcessServlet threw exception
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: The absolute uri: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core cannot be resolved in either web.xml or the jar files deployed with this application
```

Could you tell me what is this and how to fix it?
 Thanks so much.

Comment: which jstl lib u r using? if u r using old version then use uri -  http://java.sun.com/jstl/core

Comment: possible duplicate 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4928271/jstl-1-2-the-absolute-uri-http-java-sun-com-jstl-core-cannot-be-resolved