# Error: The absolute uri: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core cannot be resolved in either web.xml or the jar files deployed with this application

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, jstl

I've seen a lot of posts for this but all of them assume I have a knowledge of java that I don't.

The only thing I know is HTML and javascript and I want to follow the example showed in this URL:

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jstl_format_message_tag.htm

When I create an JSP with name juane.jsp in Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 6.0\webapps\juane and add the html/jsp code posted in the mentioned URL I get the error:

The absolute uri: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core cannot be resolved in either web.xml or the jar files deployed with this application

I went to Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 6.0\webapps\juane\WEB-INF\lib and see that I have jstl.jar. So not sure what is missing.

Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4928271/jstl-1-2-the-absolute-uri-http-java-sun-com-jstl-core-cannot-be-resolved Your web.xml probably specifies the wrong version of the servlet spec

Comment: This might help:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31043869/intellij-and-jsp-jstl-cannot-resolve-taglib-for-jstl-in-tomcat7/32444393#32444393