# How to make JSTL 1.2.5 work on Tomcat 7

Tags: jsp, tomcat, jsp-tags

I have been trying to make the JSTL library work for days and every time I tried it Tomcat kept showing.

```
The absolute uri: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core cannot be resolved in either web.xml or the jar files deployed with this application
```

I am using Tomcat 7.0.61 and I download the latest version of JSTL from Tomcat portal, I put three JSTL files in the WEB-INF/lib directory of my app

This is my directory structure

```
myapp
 - WEB-INF
   - lib
      - taglibs-standard-impl-1.2.5.jar
      - taglibs-standard-spec-1.2.5.jar
      - taglibs-standard-jstlel-1.2.5.jar
   - classes
index.jsp
```

and this is my index.jsp

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>JSP TEST on UBUNTU 12.10</title>
</head>
<body>
<%@ page import="java.io.*" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%!
public void getRequest(JspWriter out, HttpServletRequest request) throws IOException {
    String req = request.getParameter("text");
    out.println(req);
}
%>
<% getRequest(out, request); %>
</body>
</html>
```

I don't know which JSTL files I have to put in WEB-INF/lib or any configuration is missing in my app.

Please help

Comment: possible duplicate of [JSTL 1.2 - The absolute uri: http://java.sun.com/jstl/core cannot be resolved](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4928271/jstl-1-2-the-absolute-uri-http-java-sun-com-jstl-core-cannot-be-resolved)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to have your web.xml to be compliant and web-app compatible with Servlet3.0

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app  xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" version="3.0">
..
..
```

...
..

Answer (score 0):

Another reason for this error is jar filtering in Tomcat.

E.g. if the `tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanFilter.jarsToScan` property is set in the `tomcat/conf/catalina.properties` file, this could stop Tomcat from scanning the `taglibs*.jar` files.