# display SQL rows in table

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, html-table

How can I display all rows from SQL database in JSP table?

In order to one row represent one 'td' tag in table. This code below displays only last row from my database.

`CartController.java`:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/cart.html", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView cartPage(Model model) throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException {

    PreparedStatement pst;
    ResultSet rs;
    Connection con;

    con = db.getConnect(); 

    pst = con.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM onlineshop.cart");
    rs = pst.executeQuery();

    while (rs.next()) {
        model.addAttribute("ID", rs.getString(1));
        model.addAttribute("picture", rs.getString(2));
        model.addAttribute("name", rs.getString(3));
        model.addAttribute("company", rs.getString(4));
        model.addAttribute("type", rs.getString(5));
        model.addAttribute("price", rs.getString(6));
    }

    ModelAndView cart = new ModelAndView("Cart");

    return cart; 

}
```

and here is fragment of `Cart.jsp`:

```
<div style="padding-right: 40px">
    <table border="1">
        <tr>
            <td>ID</td>
            <td>Product</td>
            <td>Name</td>
            <td>Company</td>
            <td>Type</td>
            <td>Price</td>
            <td>Action</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>${ID}</td>
        <td><img src="${picture}"/></td>
        <td>${name}</td>
        <td>${company}</td>
        <td>${type}</td>
        <td>${price}</td>
        <td></td>
        </tr>

    </table>
</div>
```

Error:

```
type Exception report

message An exception occurred processing JSP page /WEB-INF/Cart.jsp at   line 74

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it   from fulfilling this request.

exception
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP   page /WEB-INF/Cart.jsp at line 74

71: </tr>
72: <c:forEach var="cart" items="carts">
73: <tr>
74:         <td>${cart.getID()}</td>
75:         <td><img src="${cart.getPicture()}"/></td>
76:         <td>${cart.getName()}</td>
77:         <td>${cart.getCompany()}</td>


Stacktrace:
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:574)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:476)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:396)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:340)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:168)
org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:303)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1243)
  org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1027)
 org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:971)
  org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:969)
 org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:871)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)
 org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:845)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)


root cause
javax.el.MethodNotFoundException: Method not found: class   java.lang.String.getID()
javax.el.Util.findWrapper(Util.java:351)
javax.el.Util.findMethod(Util.java:213)
javax.el.BeanELResolver.invoke(BeanELResolver.java:156)
org.apache.jasper.el.JasperELResolver.invoke(JasperELResolver.java:147)
org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:159)
org.apache.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:184)
org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.proprietaryEvaluate(PageContextImpl.java:943)
org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.Cart_jsp._jspx_meth_c_005fforEach_005f0(Cart_jsp.java:237)
org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.Cart_jsp._jspService(Cart_jsp.java:190)
org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:438)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:396)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:340)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:168)
org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:303)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1243)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1027)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:971)
 org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:969)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:871)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)
  org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:845)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)


 note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache    Tomcat/8.0.29 logs.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you're overriding cart information and obviously the last row wins the bet. You should maintain a `List` of `Cart`s in your controller and push them to your view. Then in the view, iterate through them and put them in each row.

Suppose you have a `Cart` class like this:

```
public class Cart {
    private String ID;
    private String picture;
    private String name;
    private String company;
    private String type;
    private String price;

    // getters and setters
}
```

Change your controller to create a `List` of `Cart`s and add each `Cart` to the list:

```
...
List<Cart> carts = new ArrayList<>();
while (rs.next()) {
            Cart cart = new Cart();
            cart.setID(rs.getString(1));
            cart.setPicture(rs.getString(2));
            cart.setName(rs.getString(3));
            cart.setCompany(rs.getString(4));
            cart.setType(rs.getString(5));
            cart.setPrice(rs.getString(6));

            carts.add(cart);
        }
model.addAttribute("carts", carts);
...
```

And in the view:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
...
<c:forEach var="cart" items="carts">
<tr>
        <td>${cart.getID()}</td>
        <td><img src="${cart.getPicture()}"/></td>
        <td>${cart.getName()}</td>
        <td>${cart.getCompany()}</td>
        <td>${cart.getType()}</td>
        <td>${cart.getPrice()}</td>
        <td></td>
</tr>
</c:forEach>
```

Comment: At this point, it's probably worth using `JdbcTemplate` as well.

Comment: or even `JPA Repository`

Comment: @AliDehghani  It looks good and I want to implement this solution, but... I got this: "Unknown tag (c:forEach)" - I imported 4 JARs (taglibs jstlel, spec, impl and compat) to my 'lib' folder and it still doesn't work...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4928271/how-to-install-jstl-the-absolute-uri-http-java-sun-com-jstl-core-cannot-be-r

Comment: Use maven or gralde for dependency management. Adding jar files to lib folder is so messy

Comment: @AliDehghani I managed with this JARs already, but here is another error..  check my post

Comment: Add full stack trace there

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99728/discussion-between-ali-dehghani-and-dante).