# Getting an unresolvable error in JSP

Tags: jsp

When I run a normal JSP code for the for loop,

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<c:forEach var="i" begin="1" end="5">
   Item <c:out value="${i}"/><p>
</c:forEach>
</body>
</html>
```

It shows me the output of

type Exception report

message : The absolute uri: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core cannot be resolved in either web.xml or the jar files deployed with this application

description: The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

I have downloaded and included JSTL 1.2 under WEB-INF/lib

Can anyone resolve this?

TIA`enter code here`

Comment: What JAR files do you have in WEB-INF/lib? Maybe there are multiple or conflicting version of JSTL.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4928271/how-to-install-jstl-the-absolute-uri-http-java-sun-com-jstl-core-cannot-be-r

Comment: still the error comes as java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/jsp/tagext/TagLibraryValidator

Comment: @abhishekjagwani did you define struts filter in web.xml ?

Comment: @abhishekjagwani you have to define  like : <filter>
      <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
      <filter-class>
         org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher
      </filter-class>
   </filter>

   <filter-mapping>
      <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
      <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
   </filter-mapping>