# Error running JSP file

Tags: jsp, servlets

I keep getting the following error when I try to run my JSP:

/JSP/Main.jsp (line: 1, column: 1) The absolute uri: http://java.sun.com/jsf/core cannot be resolved in either web.xml or the jar files deployed with this application

I have included jars jsf-api-2.0 and jsf-impl2.0.4 but I don't seem to get somewhere. I will appreciate any help rendered.

Comment: check this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4928271/how-to-install-jstl-the-absolute-uri-http-java-sun-com-jstl-core-cannot-be-r

Comment: The error disappeared when I deleted <%@ taglib prefix="f"  uri="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"%> from the top of the jsp file