# JSTL configuration

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee, jstl

I don't know what I've done incorrectly, but I can't include JSTL. I have `jstl-1.2.zip`, `taglibs-standard-jstlel-1.2.5.zip` in my WEB-INF/lib but unfortunately I get exception:

```
jsp/jstl/core cannot be resolved in either web.xml or the jar files deployed with this application
```

I included also the taglib : `<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>` in my JSP file. Please help me I couldn't find a solution for this problem, I just want to show hello world with the jstl technology so i can go and learn more about it.

[Myservlet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e5yf0.png)[MyJSPFile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o61l4.png)

Comment: Don't post text/code as image/link ([more info](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557)). Use [edit] option to correct your post.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to install JSTL? The absolute uri: http://java.sun.com/jstl/core cannot be resolved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4928271/how-to-install-jstl-the-absolute-uri-http-java-sun-com-jstl-core-cannot-be-r)

Comment: Please download jstl1.2.jar file 
-  paste it in WEBAPP/lib folder

Comment: that is what  i did bro , otherwise i stiil get the same error !

Comment: @KoheiTAMURA I followed the same tutorial but unfortunately i still get the same error

Comment: I’d like to confirm just in case; Did you unzip **zip** files?