# Hybris throws uri: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core can not be solved

Tags: java, jsp, sap-commerce-cloud

I just added a page (invoice) to the store front and i get this error, i'm not sure what caused this because yesterday i did added a simple page to test (backorder) it in the store front and it worked, now both of these pages  don't work and this appears in the console log:

```
 GRAVE: Exception Processing ErrorPage[exceptionType=java.lang.Exception, location=/exception.jsp]
 org.apache.jasper.JasperException: The absolute uri: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core can not be solved either in web.xml or the jar files deployed with this application
         at org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.jspError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:56)
         at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.dispatch(ErrorDispatcher.java:445)
         at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.jspError(ErrorDispatcher.java:117)
         at org.apache.jasper.compiler.TagLibraryInfoImpl.generateTLDLocation(TagLibraryInfoImpl.java:325)
         at org.apache.jasper.compiler.TagLibraryInfoImpl.<init>(TagLibraryInfoImpl.java:154)
         at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseTaglibDirective(Parser.java:410)
         at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseDirective(Parser.java:475)
         at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseElements(Parser.java:1410)
         at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parse(Parser.java:138)
         at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ParserController.doParse(ParserController.java:242)
         at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ParserController.parse(ParserController.java:102)
         at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.generateJava(Compiler.java:199)
         at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:374)
         at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:354)
         at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:341)
         at org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:657)
         at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:357)
         at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:395)
         at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:339)
         at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
         at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
         at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
         at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:748)
         at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInclude(ApplicationDispatcher.java:604)
         at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.include(ApplicationDispatcher.java:543)
         at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.custom(StandardHostValve.java:470)
         at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.throwable(StandardHostValve.java:420)
         at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:208)
         at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
         at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
         at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
         at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:421)
         at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1074)
         at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611)
         at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
         at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
         at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

the impex file:

```
 $contentCatalog=helvexContentCatalog
 $contentCV=catalogVersion(CatalogVersion.catalog(Catalog.id[default=$contentCatalog]),CatalogVersion.version[default=Staged])[default=$contentCatalog:Staged]
 $jarResourceCms=jar:org.helvex.com.mx.customstorefront.constants.HelvexcustomstorefrontConstants&/helvexcustomstorefront/import/cockpit/cmscockpit
 $addonExtensionName=helvexcustomstorefront


 ## Configure page ...
 INSERT_UPDATE ContentPage;$contentCV[unique=true];uid[unique=true];name;masterTemplate(uid,$contentCV);label;defaultPage[default='true'];approvalStatus(code)[default='approved'];homepage[default='false']
 ;;accountBalance;Account Balance;AccountPageTemplate;/account-balance
 ;;backOrder;Back Order;AccountPageTemplate;/back-order
 ;;invoice;Invoice;AccountPageTemplate;/invoice


 # CMS Link Component 
 INSERT_UPDATE CMSLinkComponent;$contentCV[unique=true];uid[unique=true];name;url;&linkRef;&componentRef;target(code)[default='sameWindow']
 ;;AccountBalanceLink;AccountBalanceLink;/account-balance;AccountBalanceLink;AccountBalanceLink;
 ;;BackOrderLink;BackOrderLink;/back-order;BackOrderLink;BackOrderLink
 ;;InvoiceLink;InvoiceLink;/invoice;InvoiceLink;InvoiceLink



 # CMS Navigation Nodes 

 INSERT_UPDATE CMSNavigationNode;uid[unique=true];$contentCV[unique=true];name;parent(uid, $contentCV);links(&linkRef)[mode=append];&nodeRef
 ;AccountBalanceLeftNavNode;;Check Accounts Balance;HelvexNavNode;AccountBalanceLink;AccountBalanceLeftNavNode
 ;BackOrderNavNode;;Back Order;HelvexNavNode;BackOrderLink;BackOrderNavNode
 ;InvoiceNavNode;;Invoice;HelvexNavNode;InvoiceLink;InvoiceNavNode


 # the jsp pages we defined earlier
 INSERT_UPDATE JspIncludeComponent;$contentCV[unique=true];uid[unique=true];name;page;actions(uid,$contentCV);&componentRef
 ;;AccountBalanceComponent;Check Accounts Balance Component;/WEB-INF/views/addons/$addonExtensionName/responsive/pages/accountBalancePage.jsp;;AccountBalanceComponent
 ;;BackOrderComponent;Back Order Component;/WEB-INF/views/addons/$addonExtensionName/responsive/pages/backOrderPage.jsp;;BackOrderComponen
 ;;InvoiceComponent;Invoice Component;/WEB-INF/views/addons/$addonExtensionName/responsive/pages/invoicePage.jsp;;InvoiceComponent


 # the content slots
 INSERT_UPDATE ContentSlot;$contentCV[unique=true];uid[unique=true];name;active;cmsComponents(uid,$contentCV);;;
 ;;BodyContent-accountsBalance;Body Content Slot for Accounts Balance;true;AccountBalanceComponent;;;
 ;;BodyContent-backOrder;Body Content Slot for Back Order;true;BackOrderComponent;;;
 ;;BodyContent-invoice;Body Content Slot for Invoice;true;InvoiceComponent;;;




 INSERT_UPDATE ContentSlotForPage;$contentCV[unique=true];uid[unique=true];position[unique=true];page(uid,$contentCV)[unique=true][default='accountBalance'];contentSlot(uid,$contentCV)[unique=true];;;
 ;;BodyContent-accountsBalance;BodyContent;accountBalance;BodyContent-accountsBalance;;;
 ;;BodyContent-backOrder;BodyContent;backOrder;BodyContent-backOrder;;;
 ;;BodyContent-invoice;BodyContent;invoice;BodyContent-invoice;;;
```

the web-spring.xml

```
 <bean name="accountBalancePageController" class="org.helvex.com.mx.customstorefront.controllers.pages.AccountBalancePageController"/>

     <bean name="backOrderPageController" class="org.helvex.com.mx.customstorefront.controllers.pages.BackOrderPageController"/>

     <bean name="invoicePageController" class="org.helvex.com.mx.customstorefront.controllers.pages.InvoicePageController"/>


     <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping">
             <property name="mappings">
                 <props>

                      <prop key="/account-balance">accountBalancePageController</prop>
                      <prop key="/back-order">backOrderPageController</prop>
                      <prop key="/invoice">invoicePageController</prop>

                 </props>
             </property>
     </bean>
```

What did i missed? How i can fix this error?

Comment: Please refer this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4928271/how-to-install-jstl-the-absolute-uri-http-java-sun-com-jstl-core-cannot-be

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem here is, that your application didnt find any page. And than the application tries to open a 'exception.jsp' page. But on this page as well are some errors it seems.

So maybe try to open only the 'exception.jsp' and try to fix this error first.