# How do i import JSTL library?

Tags: eclipse, jsp, jstl, buildpath

I imported JSTL in jsp page in following manner:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
```

I have added following jars to project build path:

```
jstl-1.2.jar
javax.servlet.jsp.jstl-api-1.2.1.jar
```

but when i try to run project on a tomcat server from eclipse i get following exception:

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [jsp] in context with path [/SampleWebApp] threw exception [The absolute uri: [http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core] cannot be resolved in either web.xml or the jar files deployed with this application] with root cause
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: The absolute uri: [http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core] cannot be resolved in either web.xml or the jar files deployed with this application
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.jspError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:55)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.dispatch(ErrorDispatcher.java:294)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.jspError(ErrorDispatcher.java:81)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.TagLibraryInfoImpl.generateTldResourcePath(TagLibraryInfoImpl.java:251)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.TagLibraryInfoImpl.<init>(TagLibraryInfoImpl.java:122)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseTaglibDirective(Parser.java:431)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseDirective(Parser.java:489)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseElements(Parser.java:1445)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parse(Parser.java:144)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ParserController.doParse(ParserController.java:244)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ParserController.parse(ParserController.java:105)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.generateJava(Compiler.java:206)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:385)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:362)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:346)
    at org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:603)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:369)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:386)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:330)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:494)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:137)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:651)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:754)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1376)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

How do i fix this?

Comment: take a look at this : https://stackoverflow.com/a/4928309/755401 you havea version problem in your declaration

Comment: I have switched to GlassFish and it worked, but i am still unable to run it on Tomcat.