# <jstl 1.2><tomcat8.0.5><jdk1.8>http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core cannot be resolved in either web.xml or the jar files deployed with this application

Tags: java, spring, jstl, tomcat8, servlet-3.0

**I created a simple Spring-mvc project, but i get this exception:**
 my environment：

- jdk 1.8
- tomcat 8.0.5

here is my error logs:

```
 org.apache.jasper.JasperException: The absolute uri: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core cannot be resolved in either web.xml or the jar files deployed with this application
org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.jspError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:55)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.dispatch(ErrorDispatcher.java:277)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.jspError(ErrorDispatcher.java:75)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.TagLibraryInfoImpl.generateTldResourcePath(TagLibraryInfoImpl.java:250)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.TagLibraryInfoImpl.<init>(TagLibraryInfoImpl.java:125)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseTaglibDirective(Parser.java:421)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseDirective(Parser.java:479)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseElements(Parser.java:1435)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parse(Parser.java:139)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.ParserController.doParse(ParserController.java:227)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.ParserController.parse(ParserController.java:100)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.generateJava(Compiler.java:201)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:358)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:338)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:325)
org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:586)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:363)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:396)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:340)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:168)
org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:303)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1228)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1011)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:955)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:877)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:966)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:857)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:842)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

this is my pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>spring.mvc.example</groupId>
<artifactId>example</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.12</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Spring MVC support -->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

this is my web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">
<display-name>Spring Web MVC Hello World Application</display-name>
<!-- dispatcher servlet -->
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
        org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
    </servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

here is my simple jsp demo:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>

<html>
<head>
<title>Spring MVC Hello World</title>
</head>

<body>
    <h2>All Employees in System</h2>

    <table border="1">
      <tr>
          <th>Employee Id</th>
          <th>First Name</th>
          <th>Last Name</th>
      </tr>
    <c:forEach items="${employees}" var="employee">
        <tr>
            <td>${employee.id}</td>
            <td>${employee.firstName}</td>
            <td>${employee.lastName}</td>
        </tr>
    </c:forEach>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

i searched many times, bu no answers can help me.
i am using tomcat v8.0 and jdk 1.8 and jstl 1.2, i think the Version is matched

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4928271/how-to-install-jstl-the-absolute-uri-http-java-sun-com-jstl-core-cannot-be-r possible duplicate

Comment: Specifically, see this answer on the above question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7667173/1601729

Comment: try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4928271/how-to-install-jstl-the-absolute-uri-http-java-sun-com-jstl-core-cannot-be-r?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Answer (score 1):

thanks, my problem solved.
i just put jstl-1.2.jar into TOMCAT/lib.
but i am curious about why should i add this jar file into tomcat/lib?
i already add this jar in pom.xml;

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

so it is my another problem