# How to configure taglib with servlet 4.0

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, servlets, jstl

My application is running on Tomcat 9.
I want to use servlet 4.0 and taglibs in my jsp application.

Header of my jsp is :

Error is : Can not find the tag library descriptor for "http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"

To solve the issue I have added JSTL dependency but the servlet version does not match to 4.0.

The following dependency belongs to servlet 2.4.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    <version>1.2</version>
</dependency>
```

The following dependency belongs to servlet 2.5.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.web</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.5</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: What error do you get ?

Comment: org.apache.jasper.JasperException: The absolute uri: [http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core] cannot be resolved in either web.xml or the jar files deployed with this application

Comment: [1] Your post states _"Header of my jsp is :"_, but there is nothing following that. Can you update your post to fix that? [2] See [this SO answer for the error message you are getting](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4928309/2985643). That answer is over 7 years old, so obviously it does not apply to your specific problem and the versions you are using, but its very detailed explanation may be helpful anyway.

Answer (score 0):

It must be a dependency project problem.

I managed to get spring-boot jsp [sample](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/tree/master/spring-boot-samples/spring-boot-sample-web-jsp) running.

It embeds version 9.0.10 of tomcat and depends on version 1.2 of jstl library

Comment: The artifact javax.servlet:jstl:1.2 is vulnerable to XML External Entity (XXE) Injection (https://snyk.io/vuln/SNYK-JAVA-JAVAXSERVLET-30449).

Comment: The artifact org.apache.taglibs:taglibs-standard-impl:1.2.5 is not vulnerable.