# Unable to find taglib [c] for URI: [jakarta.tags.core] Tomcat 10.1.x

Tags: gradle, jstl, tomcat10

after migrating to spring 6.0.11 and tomcat 10.1.13, we started getting problems with jstl and jsp.
According to the Jakarta Standard Tag Library 3.0 documentation, Ive changed the taglib uri in all .jsp files from **<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>** to **<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="jakarta.tags.core" %>**. After debugging, I saw that the map in the TldCache class was not filled in, which is why TagLibraryInfoImpl receives tldResourcePath as null.
All the necessary libs are installed

```
implementation 'jakarta.servlet.jsp.jstl:jakarta.servlet.jsp.jstl-api:3.0.0'
implementation 'org.glassfish.web:jakarta.servlet.jsp.jstl:3.0.1'
implementation 'org.mortbay.jasper:apache-jsp:10.1.7'
implementation("org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-jsp-api:10.1.13")
compileOnly "jakarta.servlet:jakarta.servlet-api:6.0.0"
```

what could be the problem?

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Could not find taglib [c] for URI: [jakarta.tags.core]
    in org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.jspError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:54)
    in org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.dispatch(ErrorDispatcher.java:294)
    in org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.jspError(ErrorDispatcher.java:81)
    in org.apache.jasper.compiler.TagLibraryInfoImpl.<init>(TagLibraryInfoImpl.java:176)
    in org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseTaglibDirective(Parser.java:429)
    in org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseDirective(Parser.java:487)
    in org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseElements(Parser.java:1444)
    in org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parse(Parser.java:138)
    in org.apache.jasper.compiler.ParserController.doParse(ParserController.java:245)
    in org.apache.jasper.compiler.ParserController.parse(ParserController.java:106)
    in org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.generateJava(Compiler.java:211)
    in org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:396)
    in org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:372)
    in org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:356)
    in org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:603)
    in org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:396)
    in org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:380)
    in org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:328)
    in jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:658)
    in org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:205)
    in org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149)
    in org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
    in org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174)
    in org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149)
    in org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:110)
    in org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174)
    in org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149)
```

I tried also add aditional dependecies, like

```
compileOnly 'jakarta.servlet.jsp:jakarta.servlet.jsp-api:3.1.1'
implementation 'org.mortbay.jasper:taglibs-standard:10.0.2'
compileOnly 'jakarta.platform:jakarta.jakartaee-api:10.0.0'
```

but it also didnt help. with tomcat 9 and java EE it was easy, simple add

```
implementation "jstl:jstl:1.2"  
implementation("org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-jsp-api:9.0.33")
```

and we got path to differents tags and all works.

I also have custom tags:

```
<taglib xmlns="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee/web-jsptaglibrary_3_1.xsd"
        version="3.1">
    ...
```

and with custom tags any problem, I don't understand how apache-jsp should resolve path for tags jakarta.tags.*

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Migration to Jakarta EE: Unable to find taglib \[c\] for URI: \[jakarta.tags.core\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74585710/migration-to-jakarta-ee-unable-to-find-taglib-c-for-uri-jakarta-tags-core)

Comment: @Pino unfortunately not, I have all these dependencies
I don't understand how it should resolve tag path, like jakarta.tags.core

Comment: The exception you got tells the otherwise. I don't do Gradle but it surprises me that you declared apache-jsp and tomcat-jsp with same scope as JSTL ("implementation") while Tomcat **already** ships JSP out the box. If you were using Maven, this is the duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4928271/how-to-install-jstl-the-absolute-uri-http-java-sun-com-jstl-core-cannot-be-r You just need to translate that to Gradle, including all links therein.

Comment: @BalusC thanks for the info. Yes you are right, I can remove apache-jsp, because it is already in tomcat-jsp, but then the same error occurs. it's just that without it my IDEA doesn't allow me to go to the library class to see what's going on. I saw this topic, and do everything to tomcat 10.1.x , changed tags to jakarta.tags.*,  installing dependencies, API, and implementation. This post says to use the API from org.glassfish.web, but it doesn't exist, so I use jakarta.servlet.jsp.jstl:jakarta.servlet.jsp.jstl-api and implementation from glasfish

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem.
I have context.xml with JarScanFilter and I used for scanning old jar naming.
after changing to `tldScan="jakarta.servlet.jsp.jstl*.jar all works`
[old naming for tld jar scan](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LjI9C.png)