# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: jakarta/servlet/jsp/jstl/core/Config in Tomcat

Tags: java, maven, tomcat

I read through other post and they specified that adding jstl dependency into the pom.xml would work, however, I tried doing exactly that and the error still persists:

Full pom.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
        <relativePath/>
    </parent>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>springmvctest</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <name>springmvctest</name>
    <description>springmvctest</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

     

      <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
      </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
                <exclusions>
                          <exclusion>
                            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
                          </exclusion>  
                </exclusions>                               
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>

    <build>
            <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

I have followed clean package procedure in Maven, the Spring web app starts up perfectly without any issues, but when I return a view name in the controller method it throws the error:[image]

I'm using Tomcat 10.0.21 and Spring.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

pom.xml **remove** this

```
      <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
      </dependency>
```

pom.xml add this

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>jakarta.servlet.jsp.jstl</groupId>
    <artifactId>jakarta.servlet.jsp.jstl-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0</version>
</dependency>


<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.web</groupId>
    <artifactId>jakarta.servlet.jsp.jstl</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

## showList.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
    
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>JSTL Test - Show List</title>
</head>

<body>
        <h1>JSTL Test</h1>
 
        <p>
            Show List:
            <ul>
                <c:forEach items="${list}" var="animal">
                    <li>${animal}</li>
                </c:forEach>        
            </ul>
        </p>

</body>
</html>
```

Test OK under `apache-tomcat-10.1.4`