# The tag handler class for "c:out" (org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.rt.core.OutTag) was not found on the Java Build Path

Tags: java, eclipse, jstl

I have all the jar files like JSTL and standard to the lib folder under WEB-INF but still showing the error.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x9QZG.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to install JSTL? The absolute uri: http://java.sun.com/jstl/core cannot be resolved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4928271/how-to-install-jstl-the-absolute-uri-http-java-sun-com-jstl-core-cannot-be-r)

Comment: Did you add them after the JSP file? Are automatic builds (and automatic revalidation on file changes) enabled?