# Unable to use JSTL Library in my JSP Page

Tags: java, tomcat9

HTTP Status 500 – Internal Server Error
Type Exception Report

Message org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Failed to load or instantiate TagLibraryValidator class: [org.apache.taglibs.standard.tlv.JstlCoreTLV]

Description The server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request.

Exception

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Failed to load or instantiate TagLibraryValidator class: [org.apache.taglibs.standard.tlv.JstlCoreTLV]
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:589)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:425)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:380)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:328)
jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:777)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
ServletDemo.doGet(ServletDemo.java:26)
jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:668)
jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:777)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
Root Cause

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Failed to load or instantiate TagLibraryValidator class: [org.apache.taglibs.standard.tlv.JstlCoreTLV]
org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.jspError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:54)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.dispatch(ErrorDispatcher.java:294)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.jspError(ErrorDispatcher.java:142)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.TagLibraryInfoImpl.createValidator(TagLibraryInfoImpl.java:360)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.TagLibraryInfoImpl.(TagLibraryInfoImpl.java:195)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseTaglibDirective(Parser.java:429)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseDirective(Parser.java:487)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseElements(Parser.java:1444)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parse(Parser.java:138)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.ParserController.doParse(ParserController.java:244)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.ParserController.parse(ParserController.java:105)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.generateJava(Compiler.java:206)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:391)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:367)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:351)
org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:603)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:399)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:380)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:328)
jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:777)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
ServletDemo.doGet(ServletDemo.java:26)
jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:668)
jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:777)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
Root Cause

java.lang.ClassCastException: class org.apache.taglibs.standard.tlv.JstlCoreTLV cannot be cast to class jakarta.servlet.jsp.tagext.TagLibraryValidator (org.apache.taglibs.standard.tlv.JstlCoreTLV is in unnamed module of loader org.apache.catalina.loader.ParallelWebappClassLoader @7afe1ed7; jakarta.servlet.jsp.tagext.TagLibraryValidator is in unnamed module of loader java.net.URLClassLoader @2d38eb89)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.TagLibraryInfoImpl.createValidator(TagLibraryInfoImpl.java:356)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.TagLibraryInfoImpl.(TagLibraryInfoImpl.java:195)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseTaglibDirective(Parser.java:429)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseDirective(Parser.java:487)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseElements(Parser.java:1444)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parse(Parser.java:138)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.ParserController.doParse(ParserController.java:244)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.ParserController.parse(ParserController.java:105)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.generateJava(Compiler.java:206)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:391)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:367)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:351)
org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:603)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:399)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:380)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:328)
jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:777)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
ServletDemo.doGet(ServletDemo.java:26)
jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:668)
jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:777)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
Note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the server logs.

Apache Tomcat/10.0.21

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to install JSTL? The absolute uri: http://java.sun.com/jstl/core cannot be resolved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4928271/how-to-install-jstl-the-absolute-uri-http-java-sun-com-jstl-core-cannot-be-r)

Comment: You are using the wrong version of JSTL: version 2.0 or higher is required on Tomcat 10.

Comment: Thank you so much Piotre P. Karwasz. I changed JSTL Version for Tomcat 10. It is working now. Thanks you again.