# A problem was encountered using TagExtraInfo class org.apache.taglibs.standard.tei.ForEachTEI for c:forEach' (c:out is still working perfect)

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, tomcat, jstl

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yBPQn.png)

Currently I'm using:

1. Eclipse Version: 2023-06
2. Tomcat v10.1.12
3. web.xml file

```
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee" xsi:schemaLocation="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee/web-app_6_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="6.0">
```

4. tag:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="jakarta.tags.core" %>
```

5. jstl:

```
WEB-INF/lib/jakarta.servlet.jsp.jstl-3.0.1.jar
WEB-INF/lib/jakarta.servlet.jsp.jstl-api-3.0.0.jar
```

c:out still working but c:forEach not

Error: A problem was encountered using TagExtraInfo class org.apache.taglibs.standard.tei.ForEachTEI for c:forEach'

Anyone can help?

I don't use Maven, I already try low version of jakatar.servlet jstl such as 2.0.0, ..
I follow by this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4928271/how-to-install-jstl-the-absolute-uri-http-java-sun-com-jstl-core-cannot-be-r) but not work for me.