# <c:import var="lib" url="someURL.xml"/> not saving xml content in var variable resulting in <x:parse/> not having anything to read

Tags: jstl

When I use

```
<c:import var="lib" url="someURL.xml"/>
```

the content is not being saved in the var lib thusly resulting in a premature end of file error in the first line, because there is nothing to read.

The browser will show the content of the XML document but wont be saved into a variable when called with `<x:parse/>`.

Is there some sort of configuration I'm missing, or what else could be the reason?

Comment: Use the J! button in the Breakpoints view to halt on that SAXException and then debug your JSP. Try to see why it's being thrown.

Comment: im really trying to figure out, it could be in the xml document but its extremely simple, so I dont know how the error could be there. Went to check the supposed duplicate answer, and It doesnt really relates to mine. even if its the same error. Have seen a bunch of no attachment issues, so i cant really check them in depth. But they all seem to be in the tomcat jars. Currently trying to figure out the SaxeException, so far I managed to find that it comes From a XMLParserException. Im I being dumb and not seeing something obvious? thanks for the answer

Comment: The currently linked duplicate is indeed horribly unhelpful but it essentially boils down to that the supplied XML file is null or empty. So, in your specific case, either the specified path is wrong or the file is not actually there in the WAR deployment where you expected it to be.

Comment: I found out that my <c:import var="lib" url="someUrl.xml"/> is printing the content in the browser directly, I also found out that this behaviour is the default behaviour of c:import withouth the var attribute specified. We have come to the conclusion that it means that the variable is not being saved. Meaning my x:parse indeed has nothing to read. This leads me to two conclusions. the code is reading the correct xml document, but its not behaving properly as its not saving the content in the variable. Im still on the case D: thanks for the replies, any further advice would be appreciated

Comment: Probably your JSTL version is hopelessly outdated or your JSTL install is done wrongly. Ensure that you've understood and followed the instructions in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4928309. By the way, in your future questions do not use [java] tag as long as the problem is not demonstrable in a plain vanilla Java application class with a main() method. "Java experts" are **not** per definition "JSTL experts".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to Find a solution to my problem, It was a config issue, and I couldn't find out what to do.
So I changed my approach and I Tried doing something different, changed server to Tomcat 9.0 and used the following libraries.

- taglibs-standard-impl-1.2.5.jar
- taglibs-standard-jstlel-1.2.5.jar
- taglibs-standard-spec-1.2.5.jar
- serializer-2.7.1.jar
- xalan-2.7.1.jar

used the following tags:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/xml" prefix="x" %>
```

And this works perfectly, maybe one Day I will be able to find out what went wrong with tomcat 10.1 and jakarta 3.0.0.

Thanks for all the answers {:D!