# Where do i put JSTL taglibs after downloading them

Tags: apache, jsp, servlets, netbeans, web-applications

kept getting this error when i run my web application :

```
HTTP Status 500 - The absolute uri: http://java.sun.com/jstl/core cannot be resolved in either web.xml or the jar files deployed with this application

type Exception report

message The absolute uri: http://java.sun.com/jstl/core cannot be resolved in either web.xml or the jar files deployed with this application

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: The absolute uri: http://java.sun.com/jstl/core cannot be resolved in either web.xml or the jar files deployed with this application
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.jspError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:56)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.dispatch(ErrorDispatcher.java:445)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.jspError(ErrorDispatcher.java:117)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.TagLibraryInfoImpl.generateTLDLocation(TagLibraryInfoImpl.java:311)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.TagLibraryInfoImpl.<init>(TagLibraryInfoImpl.java:152)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseTaglibDirective(Parser.java:410)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseDirective(Parser.java:475)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseElements(Parser.java:1427)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parse(Parser.java:138)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.ParserController.doParse(ParserController.java:242)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.ParserController.parse(ParserController.java:102)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.generateJava(Compiler.java:198)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:373)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:353)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:340)
    org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:646)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:357)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    myPackage.Register.processRequest(Register.java:63)
    myPackage.Register.doGet(Register.java:81)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)

note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/7.0.42 logs.
Apache Tomcat/7.0.42
```

and when i did some search i found that i need to download JSTL taglibs, i downloaded it but i don't know what to do with the files now, is there a specific folder i should put them so that my code runs fine?

Comment: Please look this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1896449/error-adding-taglib-directive-in-jsp

Answer (score 0):

From eclipse: 
1.

Right Click --> properties --> Java Build Path --> Libraries -- > Add external jars

- this will add jar to your eclipse biuld path

Right Click --> Deployment Assembly--> Java Build Path entries --> add JSTL jar

- this will add the jar to WAR file when deploying it to the server.