# Is usage of <c:out> tag with escapeXml="false" equivalent to not using <c:out> tag?

Tags: jsp, jstl, xss

I have read that using `<c:out>` tag will prevent XSS attacks but for some cases, say for example, displaying units with superscript (kg/m<sup>3</sup>) using `<c:out>` is displayed as plain text with sup tag (`kg/m<sup>3</sup>)`. In order to display it properly, `escapeXml="false"` has to be used.

```
<c:out value="${units}" escapeXml="false></c:out>
```

But I was wondering whether using `<c:out>` tag with `escapeXml="false"` is equivalent to not using `<c:out>` tag itself?

Comment: Yes, it's equivalent to not using `c:out` at all.

Answer (score 1):

```
<c:out value="${units}" escapeXml="false" />
```

This is indeed equivalent to not using `<c:out>`, but **only** in JSP 2.0 or newer.

```
${units}
```

In older JSP versions (JSP 1.x), EL in template text like above was *not* supported and therefore `<c:out>` was the only way to print EL expressions.

#### See also:

- [XSS prevention in JSP/Servlet web application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2658922/xss-prevention-in-jsp-servlet-web-application)
- [EL expressions not evaluated in JSP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30080810/el-expressions-not-evaluated-in-jsp)