# Unable to display session attribute on jsp page

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, httpsession

I am trying display a session attribute on this jsp page:

```
<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<%@ page session="true" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
        <title>title</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
    <c:choose>
        <c:when test="${error}">
            Erro.
            <br />
        </c:when>
        <c:otherwise>
            <c:out value="${sessionScope.login}"/> | <a href="<c:url value = "/logout"/>">Sair</a>.
            <br />
        </c:otherwise>
    </c:choose>
    <script src="/js/script.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

this page is forwarded from this servlet:

```
package org.loja.app.servlet;

import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

public class LoginServlet extends HttpServlet {
    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        String login = request.getParameter("login");
        String password = request.getParameter("password");

        if(password.equals("123")) {
          HttpSession session = request.getSession();
          session.setAttribute("login", login);
          request.setAttribute("error", false);
          request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/jsp/index.jsp").forward(request, response);
        } else {
          request.setAttribute("error", true);
          request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/jsp/index.jsp").forward(request, response);
        }
    }
}
```

when I open the page on the browser, instead of the attribute value, I get the text `${sessionScope.login}`.

What I am missing here?

Comment: In your directive at the top, try putting a space between <%@ and taglib

Comment: @BradleyD I made this change, but got the same result.

Comment: OK.  Try single quotes around ${sessionScope.login} in <c:out value="${sessionScope.login}"/> instead of double

Comment: Also, try adding this directive <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"%>

Comment: @BradleyD add the directive and tru use single and double quotes. still the same result.

Comment: Try check see if any EL expressions work at all. Set one before the password.equals condition: `request.setAttribute("hello world");`

Then in jsp: `{test}`

Comment: @JonathanLaliberte looks like c:out is not working, but c:url  is working fine.

Comment: Dude try doing c:out without the when conditions, saying it's not working does not give us anything to go by. Have you tried doing it without c:out? Just: `<p>{test}</p>`   *can't edit my previous comment, forgot to add the "test" before "hello world"

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't seem to be anything that is wrong by the looks of it. However here are a couple things i would try:

Remove this tag from the top:

```
<%@ page session="true" %>
```

The default behaviour is set to true anyway. There's no need to declare it again. Maybe this is invalidating the session variables you set.

**Server configuration**

Some servers have configuration settings where you need to enable session support. Perhaps this is not turned on or has been turned off.

You say that `<c:out` doesn't work but `<c:url` does. If `<c:url` works but `<c:out` doesn't then maybe your .jar jstl file is corrupted? But i highly doubt that. I think the problem lies with just that the sessionScope isn't set. Why not just try and access the variable directly? `sessionScope` isn't necessary.

Try:

```
   <c:out value="${login}"/> | <a href="<c:url value = "/logout"/>">Sair</a>.
```

Also try it without JSTL:

```
 ${login} | <a href="/logout">Sair</a>.
```

Try setting it in the jsp:

```
<c:set var="testVar" value="Hello world" scope="session"/>
<c:out value="${testVar}"/>
```

Lastly, make sure you are actually setting the variable. Test for it like this:

```
    HttpSession session = request.getSession(); //move outside to test it 
          session.setAttribute("login", login);  //move outside to test it 

if(password.equals("123")) {

          request.setAttribute("error", false);
          request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/jsp/index.jsp").forward(request, response);
        } else {
          request.setAttribute("error", true);
          request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/jsp/index.jsp").forward(request, response);
        }
```

Try these troubleshooting steps and hopefully it should help you narrow down the problem.

Comment: Since yesterday, I have tried all the troubleshooting steps you mentioned, but none solve the problem. I tested other JSTL tags, like c:forEach, c:forTokens, and these work fine too, like c:url, but tags like c:out and c:if do not work (seems like what not working it's the processing of `${...}` variables).

Comment: so you tried it without jstl and it didn't work? Do you want to teamviewer really quickly so i can see what is happening exactly?

Comment: never mind, i already solve the problem (with the orientation from the answer in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30080810/el-expressions-not-evaluated-in-jsp).