# ${object.property} is displayed as string and not displaying the value

Tags: maven, struts-1

I'm pretty new with maven and struts and I want to display a value in a table.
I'm working on a project working on my coworkers computer but not mine.
When i write the following line, I expect to get the value.

```
<td>${currentRequest.request.label}</td>
```

Instead, I display this line as if it was a string.
I know that, codewise, this line is well written.
What I don't know is what is change configuration-wise to be able to work with struts correctly.

I am using Tomcat 7.072, Struts 1.1 and Maven 3.6.0. My IDE is IntelliJ Idea.
I already checked into my .m2 folder and I can find Struts 1 in the repository.
I have tried "mvn -install" and pretty much every command that looks like to deal with dependencies that I know.

I think the problem should come from my Tomcat's configuration but I don't understand what is missing.

I would like to know where my problem is and how I can solve it.

EDIT : 
After working a bit more on this problem, it seems that the problem come from Apache, but still I don't understand why my pages won't display the proper values.

Comment: [Start here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30080810/438992) and take it from there. There's no legitimate reason you should be running S1.1, though.

Comment: Thanks Dave for your answer, the only reason I use Struts 1 is because the project already runs with it and nobody has plan to evolve it

Comment: After trying several times, your solution doesn't work in my case.

Comment: Without any other information it's impossible to help further. This is likely either a Tomcat version issue or a web.xml issue.

Comment: I solved my problem. It seems that my tomcat environment wasn't all that good. I tried with another tomcat, v.7.0.29. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Cool, glad you got it working.