# ModelAndView doesn't return data to JSP

Tags: java, spring, jsp, redirect, modelandview

I'm trying to send the data to JSP from Controller using ModelAndView.
But it doesn't show..
What am I missing? Do I have to do something more?

This is my Controller.

```
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.RedirectView;

@RestController
public class RobotpaymentController {

    @RequestMapping(value="/seikyu", method={RequestMethod.GET}, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ModelAndView seikyu(HttpServletRequest request) {
        RedirectView redirectView;
        ModelAndView mv;

        String seikyuId = request.getParameter("seikyuId");

        redirectView = new RedirectView("/pages/error.jsp");
        mv = new ModelAndView(redirectView);
        mv.addObject("title", "エラー");
        mv.addObject("message1", "ご連絡ください。");

        return mv;  
    }
}
```

And this is JSP.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head> 
  <title></title>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html" charset="UTF-8"/>

  <script src="/assets/js/common/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body style="height: auto; min-height: 100%; background:#ecf0f5;">
    <div class="wrapper" style="height: auto; min-height: 100%;">
        <header class="main-header"></header>
        <div class="content-wrapper" style="min-height: 1046px;">
            <section class="content-header"></section>
            <section class="content">
                <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-offset-2">
                    <div class="box box-default">
                        <div class="box-header with-border">
                            <i class="fa fa-warning text-red"></i>
                            <h3 class="box-title"><strong>${title}</strong></h3>
                        </div>
                        <div class="box-body">
                            <h4>${message1}</h4>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                </div>
            </section>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

And this is the image file.
As you can see ModelAndView return parameters as querystring but it doesn't show up in JSP.
[image]

---

I changed Java Code and JSP.

```
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.RedirectView;

@Controller
public class RobotpaymentController {

    @RequestMapping(value="/seikyu", method={RequestMethod.GET})
    public ModelAndView seikyu(HttpServletRequest request) {
        RedirectView redirectView;
        ModelAndView mv;

        String seikyuId = request.getParameter("seikyuId");

        redirectView = new RedirectView("/pages/error.jsp");
        //redirectView.setExposeModelAttributes(false);

        mv = new ModelAndView(redirectView);
        mv.addObject("title", "エラー");
        mv.addObject("message1", "ご連絡ください。");

        return mv;  
    }
}
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head> 
  <title></title>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html" charset="UTF-8"/>

  <script src="/assets/js/common/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body style="height: auto; min-height: 100%; background:#ecf0f5;">
    <div class="wrapper" style="height: auto; min-height: 100%;">
        <header class="main-header"></header>
        <div class="content-wrapper" style="min-height: 1046px;">
            <section class="content-header"></section>
            <section class="content">
                <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-offset-2">
                    <div class="box box-default">
                        <div class="box-header with-border">
                            <i class="fa fa-warning text-red"></i>
                            <h3 class="box-title"><strong><%= request.getParameter("title") %></strong></h3>
                        </div>
                        <div class="box-body">
                            <h4><%= request.getParameter("message1") %></h4>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                </div>
            </section>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

[image]

It worked but I want to use `${}` instead of `<%= %>`. 
Also I didn't want to be shown query string on URL so I added line `redirectView.setExposeModelAttributes(false);` but this api seems to remove parameters from URL and nothing to be shown again.

Comment: Can you check by removing `produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE`?

Comment: Still not working...

Answer (score 1):

To access parameters taken from a query string in jsp, you need to use `param` object.
You need to change your jsp like this.

```
<h3 class="box-title"><strong>${param.title}</strong></h3>
```

```
<h4>${param.message1}</h4>
```

**NOTE**
Your JSP and Controller should work even if you don't remove `produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE` and don't change `@RestController` to `@Controller`. However they do nothing when you return `ModelAndView` from your controller's method. So I also suggest that you remove `produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE` and change `@RestController` to `@Controller`.

**See Also**
[How to get parameters from the URL with JSP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1890438/how-to-get-parameters-from-the-url-with-jsp)

---

**EDIT1**
To avoid exposing the data to URL, I’d like to show 2 alternative solutions.

**1) Use ‘forward’ instead of ‘redirect’** 
When your controller ‘forwards’ the request to the JSP, the HTTP request is dispatched to the JSP internally in your server(not via web browser). So you can pass the data to the JSP not exposing it to the web browser.

Your controller’s method will be something like below.

```
    @RequestMapping(value="/seikyu", method={RequestMethod.GET})
    public String seikyu(HttpServletRequest request. Model model) {

        String seikyuId = request.getParameter("seikyuId");
        ....
        model.addAttribute("title", "エラー");
        model.addAttribute("message1", "ご連絡ください。");

       // If you  configure ‘ViewResolver’ like `registry.jsp("/WEB-INF/",".jsp”)`
       // you can ‘forward’ the request to the /WEB-INF/redirect.jsp by returning “redirect”.
        return “redirect”;  
    }
```

What string you have to return from the method depends on your `ViewResolver` configuration and the path of the JSP.


**2) Use `RedirectAttributes` and redirect the request to the JSP 'via' a controller.**
When you put the data by using `RedirectAttributes#addFlashAttribute`, you can access the data in the next HTTP request. The data put by `RedirectAttributes#addFlashAttribute` is made accessible by Spring in the next request so you can not access the data if you redirect the request directly to the JSP. So you have to redirect it to another controller's method and make the method forward it to the JSP.

Your controller’s method will be something like below.

```
    @RequestMapping(value="/seikyu", method={RequestMethod.GET})
    public String seikyu(HttpServletRequest request. RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes) {

        String seikyuId = request.getParameter("seikyuId");
        ....
        redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("title", "エラー");
        redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("message1", "ご連絡ください。");

        // If your servlet-mapping is ‘/app/*’, the string to be returned is something like this.
        return “redirect:/app/fromRedirect”;  
    }

   @RequestMapping("/fromRedirect")
   public String fromRedirect(....)  {
      ....
      return "redirect";
   }
```

What string you have to return from the `seikyu` method depends on your `servlet-mapping` configuration.
The `fromRedirect` method ‘forwards’ the request to the JSP like 1) example.

**See Also**
[RequestDispatcher.forward() vs HttpServletResponse.sendRedirect()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2047122/requestdispatcher-forward-vs-httpservletresponse-sendredirect)
[Spring Framework Documentation - Spring Web MVC - Flash Attributes](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web.html#mvc-flash-attributes)

Comment: Thanks for answering. I tried `${param...}` but it didn't work. And I checked the link that you recommended, I used `<%= ... %>` and it worked! But still I want to know how to use `${ ... }`.

Comment: 1)Is your `web.xml` properly configured? Please make sure that the `<web-app>` conforms to Servlet 2.4 or  newer and `<!DOCTYPE>` is removed. Please see: (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30080810/el-expressions-not-evaluated-in-jsp). 2)If you don’t want to expose the data to URL, It is a good idea to use ‘forward’ instead of ‘redirect’. I’d like to add this solution to my answer later.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the  `produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE` from your endpoint and return the ModelAndView from a normal controller instead of a `RestController`. A rest controller method only returns `json` in response and it does not resolve the view. So even if you specified a view in the `ModelAndView` object it won't get resolved as a result the model won't get binded to the jsp you provided.

```
@Controller
public class RobotpaymentController {

    @RequestMapping(value="/seikyu", method={RequestMethod.GET})
    public ModelAndView seikyu(HttpServletRequest request) {
        RedirectView redirectView;
        ModelAndView mv;

        String seikyuId = request.getParameter("seikyuId");

        redirectView = new RedirectView("/pages/error.jsp");
        mv = new ModelAndView(redirectView);
        mv.addObject("title", "エラー");
        mv.addObject("message1", "ご連絡ください。");

        return mv;  
    }
}
```

Comment: I removed ```produces``` and changed ```RestController``` to ```Controller``` but it's still not working.

Comment: Do you have the error.jsp configured correctly to display the data that you are providing as model ? @HeesunKim Could you share more details like the error.jsp and if you have customized error view the code for that as well in the question ?

Comment: Thank you for your answering. I tried to share the original file but it was too long and complicated. I just edited my question with new try but still not work with `${}`. Do I have to change the configuration when I use ModelAndView?

Comment: @HeesunKim So now your `error.jsp` is correctly getting populated but you need it to work with ${} instead of `<%= %>`. ?

Comment: Yes. Also I want query sting to be hidden when I call the JSP. I used `setExposeModelAttributes` api but this api seemed to remove parameters and data wasn't shown in JSP.