# Unable to print value of ${} variable from .jsp file, value always priting as ${x}

Tags: jsp

I am fully new in java, Seems its very silly question but I am facing issue while tying to print value from .JSP file, My output is always ${x} instead of value, Please someone help

Code Output
${x}

```
<html>
<body>
<% int x = 1;%>
<c:out value="${x}" />
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You created a scripting variable.  You are trying to access it as a scoped variable.  Do you have the JSTL directive on your page?

Comment: Hi Yes, Below are contents in my jsp file

<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>

<%@ taglib prefix = "c" uri = "http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>

<html>

<body>
<html>
<body>
<% int x = 1;%>
<c:out value="${x}" />

</body>
</html>

Comment: If you want to access a scoped variable, then you must set it in scope. For example   <% int x = 1; pageContext.setAttribute("x", x);%>

Comment: I tried, but still same output(${x}), not sure whether any issue in my eclipse 

<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>

<%@ taglib prefix = "c" uri = "http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>

<html>

<body>
<html>
<body>
<% int x = 1; pageContext.setAttribute("x", x);%>
<c:out value="${x}" />

</body>
</html>

Comment: Show us the source code that your server sent to your browser.

Comment: Hi My code is as below

1. FirstPageController.java

package com.skillsoft.controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@Controller
public class FirstPageController {
 
 @RequestMapping(value = "/first")
 public String redirect_start_page() {
  return "first_page";
 } 
}

Comment: 2. first_page.jsp
<%@page language="java" contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8" %>
<%@ taglib prefix = "c" uri = "http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
   <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
   <title>First JSP</title>
</head>
<body>
<% int x = 1; pageContext.setAttribute("x", x);%>
<c:out value="${x}" />
</body>
</html>

Comment: 3. index.jsp
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
 <title>Summer Picnic</title>
</head>

<body>
<h2>Fantabulous University Summer Picnic Program</h2>
<a href="first">Go to First Page</a>
</body>
</html>

Comment: You posted your code. But, you didn't show us what your server sends to your browser.  When you are looking at your page in your browser, right click your mouse and choose "View page source" from pop-up menu.  Does your server evaluate the JSTL tag or just send it to browser?

Comment: You should edit your question and add code to it.  Code in comments is hard to read.

Comment: Hi below are the view page source.

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
   <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
   <title>First JSP</title>
</head>
   
<body>

${x}
 
   
</body>
</html>

Comment: What is the output of a JSP with  just   ${"hello EL"}  in it?

Comment: Hi output showing as
${"hello EL"}

Comment: EL is not working.  Look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30080810/el-expressions-not-evaluated-in-jsp   Do any of BalusC solutions work for you?

Comment: Hi, Really thankful to you, adding below on .jsp file worked for me, struggling from last few days, thanks once again

<%@ page isELIgnored="false" %> 

Now output is "hello EL"